# Should I compare all fields in my class's "equals" method?

Tags: java, equals

I'm working on an application that allows the user to manage accounts. So, suppose I have an `Account` class, representing one of the user's accounts:

```java
class Account
{
    public int id;
    public String accountName;
    public String accountIdentifier;
    public String server;
    public String notes;
}
```

My `equals` method looks like this:

```java
public boolean equals(Object o)
{
    if (this == o)
        return true;
    if (o == null || !(o instanceof Account))
        return false;

    Account other = (Account) o;
    if (!accountIdentifier.equals(other.accountIdentifier))
        return false;
    if (!server.equals(other.server))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

As you can see, I'm only comparing the `accountIdentifier` and the `server`, but not the other fields. There are several reasons why I chose this approach.

1. I keep the accounts in a `List`. When the user updates an account, by changing the account name (which is just a name specified by the user to identify the account) or the notes, I can do `accountList.set(accountList.indexOf(account), account);` to update the account in the list. If `equals` compared all properties, this approach wouldn't work, and I'd have to work around it (for example by iterating over the list and checking for these properties manually).
2. This might actually be more important, but it only came to my mind after thinking about it for a while. An `Account` is uniquely identified by the `accountIdentifier` and the `server` it belongs to. The user might decide to rename the account, or change the notes, but it's still the same account. But if the server is changed, I think I would consider it a different account. The `id` is just an internal ID since the accounts are stored in a database. Even if that changed, the account is still considered the same account if the `accountIdentifier` and the `server` stayed the same.

What I'm trying to say is that I basically implemented `equals` this way to allow for shorter, more concise code in the rest of the application. But I'm not sure if I'm breaking some rules here, or if I'm doing something that might cause other developers headaches if it ever happens that someone is working with my application's API.

**Is it okay to only compare some fields in the `equals` method, or should I compare all fields?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it's definitely okay to do this. *You* get to decide what equality means for your class, and you should use it in a way that makes the most sense for your application's logic — in particular, for collections and other such classes that make use of equality. It sounds like you have thought about that and decided that the (server, identifier) pair is what uniquely distinguishes instances.

This would mean, for instance, that two instances with the same (server, identifier) pair but a different accountName are different versions of the same Account, and that the difference might need to be resolved somehow; that's a perfectly reasonable semantic.

It may make sense to define a separate `boolean allFieldsEqual(Account other)` method to cover the "extended" definition, depending on whether you need it (or would find it useful for testing).

And, of course, you should override `hashCode` [to make it consistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) with whatever definition of `equals` you go with.

Comment: I see. A different account name usually happens when the user modifies an account, so your example is spot on. I guess my question was more about if things would break if my equals() method didn't behave like `allFieldsEqual`, and since you clearly answered that, I'm going to accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should compare all of the fields that are necessary to determine equality. If the `accountIdentifier` and `server` fields are enough to determine if two objects are equal, then that is perfectly fine. No need to include any of the other fields that don't matter in terms of equality.

Comment: Equality is well-defined for my Account class. I was more worried about whether `equals` should respect my definition of equality, or some other definition (such as `a.equals(b)` iff all fields are equal). I thought this might be the case because `equals` is defined for all `Object`s, and also used by Java internally (like in `List#indexOf()`), so I might have to follow some other rules to make things work smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends depends on the semantics of your data".

For example, you might internally store a field that can be derived (calculated) from the other fields. In which case, you don't need to compare the calculated value.

As a gross generalisation, anything that cannot be derived from other fields should be included.

Comment: The fields I'm leaving out in the definition of `equals` can *not* be derived from the other fields. Most of them are supplied by the user, and only changed when the user updated the account. Is it okay to leave them out in this case as well?

Comment: That depends on how code is going to make use of your class and its .equals() method. For example, you might have code that constructs an instance "a" of the Account class based on data currently in the database, and constructs another instance "b" of the Account class based on data from the user (e.g. web form). You might want to compare those two instances for equality and only update the database if they're not equal. If only the notes field was changed, do you want to update the database? If so, you need to include the notes field in your equals implementation.

Answer (score 1):

For the key normally you should use the business key, this key can be simple or composite key and not necessary need to include all the fields in the entity. So... depends of each case to select what identify an entity. If possible should be the minimum number of field fully and unique identify the entity.

Some people prefer (and is a good practice) to create a surrogate key that will identity the object, this is very useful when you want to persist your objects using any ORM due you don’t need to export the keys to the child entities in 1:M or M:N relations. For example the ID in your sample can be considered as surrogate key if you create it as internal unique identifier.

Also may want to take into consideration:

- Always you override **equals** you must override **hashCode** too, this is important to work properly with classes like Collections, Maps etc
- Apache provide a really nice API to help in the implementation of equals and hashCode. Those classes are **EqualsBuilder** and **HashCodeBuilder**. Both allow you to concatenate the fields you want to use in your comparison and have a way also to use reflection.

Answer (score 0):

This is fine - and probably a good thing to do.  If you've identified equality as the `accountIdentifier` and the `server` being distinct and unique, then that's perfectly valid for your use case.

You don't want to use more fields than you need to since that would produce false positives in your code.  This approach is perfectly suitable to your needs.